# How to change label name in User - Profile plugin, Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, label, joomla2.5, user-profile

I have created web-site using Joomla 2.5. In this website, I have used registration. For registration I have used default Joomla registration. In form I have added Phone & Country field by activating "User - Profile" plugin. Now I want to change the lablel of Phone to Contact Number and Country to Location. Any idea how to get this done?

Note, I have changed the label of Name to Full name, Email address to Email ID in file  /language/en-GB/en-GB.com_users.ini, however I don't get where I will get data for Phone and country.

Any idea where and how  I can change? Any idea/ hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you make changes in this file /language/en-GB/en-GB.com_users.ini at administrator or front end?if not change in both.

Comment: in "/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_users.ini", there is no option for Phone and Country and hence I have this question.

Comment: I think it might be coming from the database, so it might be an idea to open phpMyAdmin and see if changing it from there helps.

Comment: not coming from DB... see my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think changing this file will do the work-

```
administrator\language\en-GB\en-GB.plg_user_profile.ini
```

**UPDATE**

Avoid changing above file, instead use language override. Below is the detail of how to override language variable-

https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla

Comment: @FahimParkar:Got at the same time.

Comment: you know what... After I ask question, I get answer in 5-10 mins myself... STRANGE BUT HAPPEN OFTEN...

Comment: It gets the job done, but it's easier and better practice to do as Brent Friar suggests.

Answer (score 3):

While these answers will work, they are not the correct way to do it. If you edit the language files, any changes you make will be overwritten if the file is ever changed in an update.

Joomla 2.0 has language overrides and a fantastic language manager to help you with the changes. All you need to do is log in to the admin, then click on Language Manager in the Extensions menu. Once there, click the Overrides link. This will give you a list of all of the overrides you have created. Click the New icon to create a new override, then simply search by either the value you want to change, or if you know it, the constant. The language manager will then search through all of your language files to find what you are looking for. when you are done click the save button and it will create an override file that will not only change what you wanted to change, but will also be safe from future updates as it does not touch the original language file.

Answer (score 0):

Open file `en-GB.plg_user_profile.ini` (administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_user_profile.ini)

Change `PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_COUNTRY_LABEL="Country"` to `PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_COUNTRY_LABEL="Location"`

that's it...

Comment: This is the worst way to do it see @Brent Friar's answer for the correct way to do it.